# SSLCertificateVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

Tags: python, exception, ssl, discord, bots

I am trying to make a Discord bot using the ChatGPT API:

```
import discord
import random
import requests

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client.send_messages = True  

api_key = '##########################################'
api_url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions'

phrases_to_check = ["come bot", "hey bot", "bot"]
farewell_commands = ["end bot", "bye bot"]

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name}')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global client  

    if client.send_messages and not message.author.bot:
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        payload = {'messages': [{'role': 'system', 'content': 'You are a helpful assistant.'}, {'role': 'user', 'content': message.content}]}
        response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=payload)
        
        if 200 <= response.status_code < 300:
            chatbot_response = response.json().get('choices')[0].get('message').get('content')
            
            await message.channel.send(chatbot_response)
        else:
            await message.channel.send(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
        
        if message.content.lower() in farewell_commands:
            
            client.send_messages = False
            await message.channel.send("Goodbye! Send 'come bot' or 'hey bot' to start chatting again.")
        
    elif message.content.lower() in phrases_to_check:
        client.send_messages = True
        
        greetings = [
            "Hello, ",
            "Hi, "
        ]
        
        response = random.choice(greetings) + random.choice(["How may I help you?", "How can I help you?", "I'm here to help!"])
        
        await message.channel.send(response)

bot_token = '########################################'
client.run(bot_token)
```

It takes a message from Discord when it is sent, and responds accordingly to it.
but when I run, there is a ssl certificate verification problem

```
2023-11-19 12:17:58 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1089, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1119, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 534, in data_received
    ssldata, appdata = self._sslpipe.feed_ssldata(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/sslproto.py", line 188, in feed_ssldata
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 974, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Bots/pybot3/main.py", line 68, in <module>
    client.run(bot_token)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 777, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 612, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 803, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 625, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1187, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 574, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1231, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1200, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 990, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorCertificateError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorCertificateError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')]
```

Please help me solve the problem, I looked at multiple different different posts, and none of them solved the problem.

Comment: *"I looked at multiple different different posts, and none of them solved the problem."* - which says exactly nothing of what you found and tried. So it is impossible to give a more focused help. Therefore I've closed the question of duplicate of several other questions with the same problem with the discord client. Hope these help - if not be more specific of what you tried.